# Next.js + JWT + Authentication + getServerSideProps - A cleaner way to achieve this?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, next.js, jwt

## The Problem

(EDIT): Probably a better summation of the issue I am trying to solve. However, he reaches the same solution as "spreadCookiesToContext(ctx, apiResponse);".

> I want to fetch my user’s data on the server before rendering the
> page, meaning I’ll first need to validate the access token, which is
> encrypted in a browser cookie. I want the ability to update, delete,
> and set multiple new cookies before rendering a page.
>
> Because I need to reuse the functionality for validating the user
> token, I need the ability to handle cookies in designated functions
> outside the scope of my getServerSideProps function. For example,
> making a request to my API from inside getServerSideProps. This is
> where things get tricky.
>
> In attempting these cookie operations, I quickly realized:
>
> It matters whether you are calling your cookie handling functions from
> getServerSideProps or normal API endpoints.
>
> I found that when testing my validation endpoints via Postman, the
> cookies were setting just fine. But when I loaded a page from
> getServerSideProps, they were not set in the browser
>
> Why is this the case?
>
> You don’t call getServerSideProps from the browser like you would an
> API route, therefore you cannot set cookies in the browser using the
> same methods. We have to work with Next.js’s context object rather
> than Node’s request object.

https://javascript.plainenglish.io/next-js-using-cookies-in-getserversideprops-89c03a216b0b

I am using getServerSideProps() on Next.js to retrieve data from an external API before page load, this is no problem. (getServerSideProps() code included for completeness):

```
async function getInitialValues(
    ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext,
): Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<Props>> {
    const { query } = ctx;
    try {
        const authTestData = await axiosAuthTest(ctx);
        spreadCookiesToContext(ctx, authTestData);

        const data = await axiosFetchData(query, ctx);

        return {
            props: {
                data: data.data,
                query,
            },
        };
    } catch (e) {
        // handle Error
    }
}
```

However, when retrieving data from a protected API route (requiring a valid access_token) and then calling another API route within the same getServerSideProps function, I must repeat the following line of code.

```
spreadCookiesToContext(ctx, apiResponse);
```

The function definition is included below:

```
function spreadCookiesToContext(
    ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext,
    res: AxiosResponse,
): Record<string, string> | null {
    const cookies: string[] | undefined =
        res.config.headers['set-cookie'] ?? res.headers['set-cookie'];
    if (cookies) {
        ctx.res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookies);
        return cookie.parse(cookies.join(';'));
    }
    return null;
}
```

This will retrieve the getServerSideProps() context and the Axios Response object and assign the "set-cookie" header.
I am doing this because a user access_token should only last 5 minutes and in the case that the access_token has expired an Axios interceptor will refresh this token before retrying the request.

The interceptor will return the response object with a new set of refresh_token and access_token that need to be saved to the user's cookies. But the refresh_token is obviously httpOnly and so only accessible on the server-side.

One fix I have come up with is to wrap any Authenticated route with this "authGuard" wrapper.

```
const testData = await authGuard<AuthTestResposne>(
    axiosAuthTest(ctx),
    ctx,
);
```

This function calls any API route and spreads the cookies to the provided getServerSideProps() context. This removes the need to repeat the spreadCookiesToContext() line from each getServerSideProps() function. Instead, all authenticated API routes must be wrapped in this authGuard wrapper.

```
async function authGuard<T>(
    apiFunc: Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>,
    ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext,
): Promise<AxiosResponse<T>> {
    const data = await apiFunc;
    spreadCookiesToContext(ctx, data);

    return data;
}
```

### Axios Interceptor Code

A G - "Why not set cookie in the interceptor itself?"

I am already setting the cookies in the interceptor, here is the code for that:

```
if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
    originalRequest._retry = true;

    const config: AxiosRequestConfig | undefined = !hasWindow
        ? {
                headers: { cookie: originalRequest.headers.cookie },
                withCredentials: true,
            }
        : undefined;

    try {
        const { data, headers } = await axiosInternalRefresh(config);
        const cookieConfig = !hasWindow
            ? { 'set-cookie': headers['set-cookie'] }
            : undefined;

        const updatedRequestWithRefreshedToken = {
            ...originalRequest,
            headers: {
                ...originalRequest.headers,
                Authorization: `Bearer ${data.accessToken}`,
                ...cookieConfig,
            },
        };

        return await axiosInstance(updatedRequestWithRefreshedToken);
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(new APIError(error));
    }
}
```

The cookie is being set by the Axios interceptor code however, this will not save the new access_token to the client browser. And the user is then logged out. The authorized API calls will correctly be retried and return the data.

```
axiosInternalRefresh(config);
```

This line of code is calling the API refresh route which will return a new pair of access and refresh tokens.

## Questions

Is there any cleaner method of achieving this functionality? Or perhaps a completely different approach to fixing this issue?

Comment: Why not set cookie in the interceptor itself?

Comment: I do set the cookie in the interceptor however this will not save the new access_token on the client-side.

I will add the interceptor code to the post now.